# jQuery: Get textarea's value and append at certain point

Tags: jquery, html, css, append, textarea

I have a textarea in my page with a default HTML value in it. I want to get its value and append a `style` tag to the `head` tag of it. How can I do this?
I tried this but had no success:

```
var html = $( 'textarea' ).val();
$( html ).find( 'head' ).append( '<style></style>' );
```

Comment: Wait, an HTML document should only have one `<head>` tag.. at the beginning of the document. What do you mean by "the head tag of _it_ "?

Comment: I mean head tag of html value in textarea.

Comment: @EhsanMousavi A textarea can have any text in it, what you are saying is not clear at all. Why would your textarea have a head tag? or any tag at all?

Comment: Haven't you seen sites like codepen or jsfiddle @Laif?

Comment: @EhsanMousavi What specifically about them? Like, you're typing in raw HTML code into a text box and not rendering it?

Comment: It's simple! I have a textarea with default html value. I'm working on a html/css workspace.

Comment: Forget about textarea. Imagine a html string.

Answer (score 1):

No need to find `head` tag. Just read value from `textarea` and append that value on `head` like below.

```js
var css = $("#txtStyle").val();
$('head').append('<style type="text/css">body {' + css + '}</style>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id='txtStyle' rows="4" cols="50">
background-color: red;
</textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks but not my answer.